# How to End HTTP Response body in node.js

Tags: node.js, httpresponse

I have created a web server which shows the directory and file listing by firing ls -l. As i am new to node.js environment, I don't know how to end HTTP Body Response for async code.
Following is my code-

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('bash');
var http = require('http');
var s = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        res.write('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        res.write('Sending stdin to terminal');
        terminal.stdin.write('ls -l\n');
        res.write('Ending terminal session');
        terminal.stdin.end();
    }, 1000);

    terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
        res.write('child process exited with code ' + code + '\n');
        res.end("Response Ended");
    });
});
s.listen(8000);
```

This code works fine for serving first request. But while serving second request there is an error: "write after end".
Why is this happening? How can i rectify this?

Comment: If you don't want to re-invent the wheel you should have a look at connect and/or [express](http://expressjs.com/). BTW you should format your code so we can read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only spawning a process once (before the server starts), so once that process has exited, you cannot write to it anymore. Try this instead:

```
var http = require('http'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var s = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var terminal = spawn('bash');

    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        res.write('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        res.write('Sending stdin to terminal');
        terminal.stdin.write('ls -l\n');
        res.write('Ending terminal session');
        terminal.stdin.end();
    }, 1000);

    terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
        res.write('child process exited with code ' + code + '\n');
        res.end("Response Ended");
    });
});
s.listen(8000);
```